# Laravel unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, laravel

My JS and images files, located in the public folder, are no longing loading.

I am using Windows 10 and XAMPP.

I was using the asset command to load them, the following way:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

I changed to this:

```
<link href="{{ asset('/public/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

and the error vanishes.

Now I get the following errors:

[image]

I have no idea how to solve the Unexpected Identifier issue.

Comment: I would say you might have changed something in script.js that causes the syntax error. As for the not found error, I'm not so sure. Do you know what exactly you changed? Are you using version control?

Comment: please post your codes and add errors as text format not pic

Comment: You need to stop take a long deep breath, hi the edit option, and try and edit this until you have a clear question that it is possible to answer. Throwing a lot of partly thought through words on the screen is no substitute for the hard work of creating and asking a good question.

Answer (score 0):

The location of the assets in your project folder is different from the one you are specifying in the HTML. The asset() function will look in the default assets directory for laravel. You must view the page source to see if the directory from where you are loading the assets is fine. Alternatively, try using the url() method instead of asset()